# Filter List of objects using Jackson's BeanPropertyFilter

Tags: java, json, filter, jackson

I had the objectList inside the main class. I am using the SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept of Jackson but I am not getting the filtered response. Can any one help me, JSON response is below.

```
{
   "person":    [
            {
         "firstName": "Shyam",
         "age": 7,
         "addressDetails":          [
                        {
               "houseNo": "1236",
               "buildingNo": "T4",
               "address1": "sector 34",
               "address2": "near hospital",
               "city": "noida",
               "state": "UP",
               "pinCode": 1400021
            },
                        {
               "houseNo": "1236",
               "buildingNo": "T4",
               "address1": "sector 34",
               "address2": "near hospital",
               "city": "noida",
               "state": "UP",
               "pinCode": 1400021
            }
         ],
         "lastName": "singh"
      }
   ],
   "syncDate": 1441167154507,
   "nextPage": "http://localhost:8080/personData/Date=1437458428657"
}
```

Comment: What does your filter code look like?

Answer (score 0):

try this, there use two loops 1st for i use to get person array data, other for j use to get address details data.

```
try {
        JSONObject responseJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String syncDate=responseJsonObject.getString("syncDate");
        String nextPage=responseJsonObject.getString("nextPage");

        JSONArray jsonPerson_jsonarray = responseJsonObject
                .getJSONArray("person");
        Log.i("get_array", jsonPerson_jsonarray + "");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonPerson_jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject personDetail = jsonPerson_jsonarray
                    .getJSONObject(i);

            String firstName=personDetail.getString("firstName");
            String age=personDetail.getString("age");
            String lastName=personDetail.getString("lastName");
            JSONArray addressDetails_jsonarray = personDetail
                    .getJSONArray("addressDetails");

            for (int j = 0; j < addressDetails_jsonarray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject addressDetails = addressDetails_jsonarray
                        .getJSONObject(j);

                String houseNo=addressDetails.getString("houseNo");
                String buildingNo=addressDetails.getString("buildingNo");
                String address1=addressDetails.getString("address1");
                String address2=addressDetails.getString("address2");
                String city=addressDetails.getString("city");
                String state=addressDetails.getString("state");
                String pinCode=addressDetails.getString("pinCode");
            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Replace for loop strings with your bean class getter setter methods or use array, and getting your desired data

Comment: thanks, but that response i am able to parse. but the issue is i need to send the partial Json response to client. based on the fields detail provided in url parameter.